# No. Of winding reason

Tags: dc-motor

Why dies the the shunt and series field in a compound dc machine have same no. of turns ? 
What happens if we equal the value of both the turns ?

Comment: They don't. Nothing interesting.

Answer (score 0):

> Why dies the the shunt and series field in a compound dc machine have
>   same no. of turns ?

I assume you mean "does" and the answer, almost certainly is that they don't.

The series winding is, as the name implies, in series with the armature and therefore carries a much bigger current that the shunt winding (parallel with the motor). Hence it has many. many fewer turns.